# Mongoose: population linked to referenced subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have to schemas in my node.js express app - User and Delivery.

```
var User = new Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    addresses: [
        {
            city: {type: String},
            address: {type: String},
        }
    ],
});
```

I can't reference User's `addresses` subdocument from Delivery schema's `address` field, so `address` field stores subdocument's `_id`.

```
var Delivery = new Schema({
    time: {type: String},
    address: {type: String} // this field references to User schema's address subdocument
});
```

So how can I populate `address` field in `Delivery` schema?

```
Delivery.findOne(/*here is condition*/).populate({path: 'address', model: 'User.addresses'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var Address = new Schema({
    city: {type: String},
    address: {type: String}
});
var AddressModel = mongoose.model('AddressModel', Address);

var User = new Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    addresses: [Address],
});

var Delivery = new Schema({
    time: {type: String},
    address: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        res: 'Address'
    }
});
```

Then:

```
Delivery.findOne(/*here is condition*/).populate('address')...
```

Comment: It's not working, address simple becomes null, without any errors. Each schema are stored in separate files - `user.js` and `delivery.js`.

Comment: @user3215609 MongoDB doesn't have joins so you have to load data from another collection manually. Or keep addresses in dedicated collection to reference them.